# Calculating index of a nested loop

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

preamble: I have used single letter variables as I am not sure what the "correct" way is, if it would be easier to understand with the full names of the variables, i can change this.

Given the following loop and nested loop which will result in "o" being the value of 14640 ("o" will at some point be any number from 0 to 14640 inclusive):

```
o = 0
m = 2
w = 241
for i = 0; i < w; i += m
   for j = 0; j < w; j += m
      o = o + 1
```

If we slightly change the above loops we can calculate the the current value of "o" within the first loop with the following modified for loop and equation, we still need "o" in the future so I will calculate "o" and store as "n":

$n=\lceil \frac{w}{m}\rceil \lceil \frac{i}{m}\rceil$

```
o = 0
m = 2
w = 241
for i = 0; i < w; i += m
   n = ceiling(w / m) * ceiling(i / m)
   for j = 0; j < w; j += m
      o = n + 1
```

My issue is when I add a third loop as below:
With the third loop, the value of "n" can be incorrect depending on the value of "c" as "i" could start on a value which should have been skipped while incrementing i by m.
for example with "c" being 5 at the end of the first loop, "i" will be 5 and subsequently "j" will equal 5, however, it should be 6.

```
o = 0
m = 2
w = 241
c = 5
for s = 0; s < w; s += c
   for i = s; i < w and i < s + c; i += m
      n = ceiling(w / m) * ceiling(i / m)
      for j = 0; j < w; j += m
         o = n + 1
```

How would I calculate the starting value of "i" is given that "s" could be a value that would make "i" start at an incorrect value?

Comment: What do you mean $i$ and $j$ will be $5$? They are both being incremented by $m$, so how could they ever be $5$?

Comment: @Anonymous every time the inner loop "i" is initialised, it is initialised to the value of s, which is incremented by "c" not "m"

Comment: Okay, yes, when the first loop is run a second time, $s$ will be incremented to $5$. Then $i$ will be initialized to the value of $s$ which is $5$. But $j$ always starts at $0$ and increments by $2$, so $j$ will always be even and never be $5$. What exactly are you trying to get the program to compute?

Comment: I think the ceilings should be floors.  In standard for loops, the comparison is always checked before the body of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

After working on something else I have come up with the following solution to calculate what the value of "i" should be initialised to.

$i=s+s\mod m$